# What do you call someone when they don't believe in something then they believe in it when they see it themselves?

Tags: meaning

Jesse didn't believe that there are notebooks, Then when he saw it for himself he believed the was.

Comment: A possible term would be [Doubting Thomas](https://overviewbible.com/doubting-thomas/). In the Gospel of John in the Christian Bible Thomas was the disciple who was not present at the first appearance of the risen Jesus to the rest of the disciples and refused to belive in the resurrection until Jesus appeared to them again. This term has become a bit detached from its origin and is often used to refer to someone who just doubts everything and is difficult to convince even when the evidence is placed before him but its origins are definitely in the situation you want to describe.

Comment: They are distrustful, skeptical, unconvinced...

Comment: Jesse might just be a ***scientist***. The astounding progress made by adopting "the scientific method" in recent centuries is almost entirely down to the principle of "Believe nothing until you've seen the evidence yourself". Before that, humanity bumbled along for millennia just accepting whatever the people in authority told them.

Comment: ...or you could perhaps consider "nounifying" adjectival ***epiphanic***.